# What is the intended way to increment or decrement a counter value, using Spring 4 data jpa with repositories?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, sql-update, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Given the following scenario:

- A shop sells products A, B and C.
- The stock amounts are A := 100, B := 100, C := 100
- A shopping cart contains 50 A, and 80 B

We have a business service providing a checkout(ShoppingCart cart) method. This method shall do two things transactional:

1. Persists the shopping cart
2. Reduce the shop stock according to the amount of products

So in our example, after checkout, we want the shop stock to be A := 50, B := 20 and C := 100.

We currently use two repository methods to do so:

- **CartRepository.save(ShoppingCart cart)**
- and, for each contained product **ShopStockRepository.incrementStock(productId, -1 * amount of product)**

incrementStock is implemented as a custom update query using the @Modifying and @Query annotations. The Query uses an UPDATE SET statement that decreases the shop stocks for the related item.

Unfortunately it turns out, that the database is correctly updated but the shop item object is not refreshed.

Using integrations tests, we found out, that if we inject the EntityManager to the checkout service and advise it, to refresh each product manually, that everything seems to works. But is this the correct way to handle this kind of incremental update???

An alternative, that we could think of, is to read the product, update the value and save it back, But wouldn't this lead to race conditions? Would we have to implement some sort of locking?

Hope you can help, we're struggling with this for days :-/

Marius

Comment: Since you are using a native query, the database will be updated fine but the in-memory objects will not know about the change.  Is there a reason why you are using a native query?  If you are storing the stock on the product, could you do `Product.reduceStock(int)`?  That way, when you save a `Cart` which has `CartItem`s, each associated with a `Product`, `cartRepository.save` will cascade all the way down to the product and update its stock correctly.  Also try not to cache products since it stores stock, which is a highly dynamic value.

Comment: Hi Manish, thank your for your response. From the sample above, following your approach I'd think (but maybe I'm wrong?), JPA repository would produce something like: 

UPDATE product SET shop_stock = 50 WHERE name = 'A'
UPDATE product SET shop_stock = 80 WHERE name = 'B'

My concern, if I change the amounts as you described is, that I may have a race condition? What if there's another process which reduced A to 90 meanwhile? Will reading the current amounts, changing them and writing them back in one method marked with @Transactional save me here? I thought, a native query would prevent this.

Comment: Do you share the database between applications?  If yes, see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741713/concurrency-of-jpa-when-same-db-used-by-other-applications/30742466#30742466) for why that is not a good idea. If you are using row-level versioning with your JPA entities, it is unlikely that multiple users will be able to modify the same entity (database row) concurrently. Unfortunately, sorting out concurrency issues of this nature is way beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow question so you will have to try some options out and post specific questions.

Comment: Nope, only multiple instances of the same server, so we could at least assure, they'd access the database in the same way.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be an issue with multiple users updating the same stock as long as you do it quickly as `get latest stock -> update -> save` so that no one user holds the stock status for long.  With a version column, users won't be able to push stock level below zero which is a real possibility with raw SQL since you aren't checking if the current stock level can serve the current order.

Comment: But would my question in the end not also apply to a single server, handling multiple requests in several threads? I thought, using the native query would, for this use case ensure, that the final result is always right cause it does:

UPDATE product SET shop_stock = shop_stock - 50 WHERE name = 'A' 
UPDATE product SET shop_stock = shop_stock - 20 WHERE name = 'B'

in contrast to the query above. It would not matter, if there would have been a transaction in between, cause the sum of all transactions would lead to the same result.

Comment: No, with a versioned row, only one user can set the version to a specific value at a time.  If multiple users obtain the same version of a row and then try to update it at different times, only one of them will succeed and all others will fail.

Comment: For the >= 0 constraint, we are using a check constraint, so that the DB will reject the transaction, so at least, that would be save. But maybe, that's also a wrong thing to do using JPA?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83100/discussion-between-manish-and-marius-schmidt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, but if you want the value to be updated next time you fetch the entity you need to add `@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)`.

For example

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, String> {

    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query("update #{#entityName} u set u.sent = u.sent + :sentIncrement, u.receipts = u.receipts + :receiptsIncrement where u.id = :id")
    int incrementSentAndReceipts(@Param("id") String id,
                                  @Param("sentIncrement") int sentIncrement,
                                  @Param("receiptsIncrement") int receiptsIncrement);
}
```

The downside is that every time you execute that query, the first level cache will be cleared and you'll force hibernate to go to the database to refresh the data.